# Is it true that if you use a preposition and then a verb, it must end with "ing"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, suffixes

I've read a grammar rule. If you use a preposition and then a verb, it must end with "ing"
Is it always true, or there are exceptions?

Comment: Related: [Nobody was surprised **at** John **being** absent (present participle or gerund?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299578/nobody-was-surprised-at-john-being-absent-present-participle-or-gerund) Emphasis in bold mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is kind of tricky, let's see if I can explain...

As Claudiu pointed out already, [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) is the term. However, expanding on what he said, "a verb ending in -ing" is not necessarily a gerund; it could be a [present participle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle#English). A gerund is an -ing form used as a *noun* (more precisely, as the head of a noun clause; it might still behave as a verb within the clause itself).

Thus, the rule you read is kind of okay, yet it is also kind of backwards. Being able to be preceded by a preposition is a [nominal characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Double_nature_of_the_gerund), not a verbal one. You can't really put a preposition in front of a verb — once you do that it needs to start functioning as a noun, and "normal" verbs can't do that. So you need a verb form that works as a noun. And that would be the gerund.

But what about this, you say:

[image: "Your shipment of fail has arrived"]

Well, yeah, the verb *fail* somehow managed to start working as a noun all by itself. But again, the whole point is that when it acts as a noun it is, well, a noun; it is no longer a verb.

Comment: I like this kind of visual support for an answer

Comment: Note that prepositions may also precede words other than nouns, as in "by the river", "with flying colours", if we take "precede" literally. They must *govern* something noun-ish, though, as Reg has explained. But I think Reg was deliberately trying to keep things simple and avoid linguistic terminology.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to generally work. Be careful when you use "to". It might be denoting the infinitive:

> I'm going to kill him.

or it might be used as a preposition:

> I am used to crying all day.

As an aside, the technical term for "a verb ending in -ing" is a [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund).

Comment: Another common mistake is "I am looking forward to do s.th." instead of the correct "I am looking forward to doing s.th."