# In "Nobody was surprised at John being absent", is "being" a present participle modifying "John" or a gerund whose subject is "John"?

Tags: gerund-phrases, participial-phrases, nonfinite-verbs, deverbal-adjectives, gerunds-vs-participles

Some time ago I learned the difference between a present participle and a gerund, so today I decided to pass any online test to make sure I understand it.

I passed it having made only one mistake, which asked the difference between the two in this sentence:

> Nobody was surprised at John being absent.

One needed to choose between present participle and gerund in reference to the word *being*.

I chose present participle because the word *being* here plays a role of an adjective apart from a verb.

I thought that if it had read *John's being*, then the word would have been a participle because it would be a noun in a form of a verb.

I know, this question is a duplicate and I agree that it should be closed, but I just would like to find out whether it was me who made a mistake or whether it was the website that diddo.

Comment: @Araucaria Oh, okay, I actually didn't even mind deleting it as a duplication because it is. But what I was interested in is this particular case of defining "being". And now I see that some answers given here might be useful for those who know the distinction between these two but came across this case and have troubles defining the word "being".

Comment: You might want to wait and see how it develops. Not many of the gerund questions here address gerunds with common nouns  in plain case as Subject. They usually have pronouns or ___'s in the questions, so yours is a bit more unusual. Btw, a gerund is always a verb, it's never a noun!

Comment: You might find [this post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73272/why-is-his-driving-the-car-wrong/73325#73325) helpful! :)

Comment: @Araucaria Is it? Oh, then it's just my Russian way of thinking. If I see an inged word and can make a "what?" question about it (like "I love swimming" - "What do I like?"), then I consider the word to be a noun. I will try to get myself used to what actually a gerund is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a gerund.  A gerund functions as a noun.  A noun is a thing.  "John being absent" is a thing.  It is the thing that nobody was surprised at.

It's not functioning as a participle.  A participle relates to a linking verb.  The only verb in the sentence is "was."  The subject of that verb is "nobody."  However, "nobody" wasn't "being absent."

It's also not functioning as a participle that is acting as an adjective.  When a present participle is being used as an adjective, it is done so like in the following: "The running car overheated."  "Being" isn't describing John like "running" is describing car.  One way that you can tell is by simply moving "being" before John.  Whereas sometimes adjectives can follow a noun, they usually appear before the noun they modify and can always be moved before it and still have it make sense.  "Being absent John" doesn't work, so "being absent" is clearly not adjectival, so "being" is not a participle standing in for an adjective.

Comment: I didn't think of analyzing it as a complex. So, if I make it posessive (John's being), nothing will change, right? It will still be a gerund.

Comment: Actually, saying "John's being" in this sentence makes it more clearly a gerund.  The apostrophe S ('s) on John makes John possessive.  Only things (nouns) can be possessed, not verbs.  The reason I say "in this sentence," however, is that "John's" in some contexts could be a contraction of "John is."  If that were the case, then "being" immediately following "John's" would be a participle, and "John's being" would be using the present progressive tense.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, if I say "John's being happy" as a sentence, not as a part of a it, "being" is a participle. And if I say "I saw him being happy", "being" is a gerund.

Comment: @user151486 "Being" is NOT an adjective, it's a verb. _John being absent_ is a gerund-participial clause (not a phrase) in which _John_ is subject, _being_ the verb and the adjective _absent_ a predicative complement. The clause functions as complement to the preposition _at_. The choice of non-genitive _John_ or genitive _John's_ is a matter of style, the latter being slightly more formal. Either way, the analysis is  the same. In traditional grammar "being" is called a gerund, but in modern grammar, it's a non-finite verb that can take various complements.

Comment: @BillJ Are you saying that the traditionalists consider "being" always to be a gerund? Even in, for instance, "I'm being happy"? Or are you talking about this particular sentence?

Comment: @user151486 This particular sentence. In trad grammar the gerund suffix formed nouns from verbs, as it still does in something like _I witnessed the 'killing of the birds'_. But in the course of time, its syntactic use was greatly extended so that it came to combine not just with dependents associated with nouns, but also with those associated with verbs e.g. _There's no point in 'killing the birds'_. The problem is that the trad definition fails to recognise the reanalysis of the form in my second example as a verb so it calls the OP's _being_ a gerund (noun), and modern gram calls it a verb.

Comment: @BillJ It looks like a gerund was invented to confuse learners. I can say "killing is an act of killing" and it will be absolutely logically.

Comment: user151486 Yes, it's a difficult aspect of our grammar. My advice is to stick with modern grammar; it's what most serious/professional grammarians and linguists do. But be careful with my example  _I witnessed 'the 'killing of the birds'_. In modern grammar, _killing_ in that example is a noun (a gerundial noun to be precise). This is evident from the fact that it takes the definite article _the_ and an _of_ phrase as complement. Verbs cannot take articles and such complements.

Comment: @user151486 : You asked: "If I say 'John's being happy' as a sentence, not as a part of an it, is 'being' a participle?"  ANSWER: Yes, you have it exactly right.

Comment: @user151486 : You asked:  "And if I say, 'I saw him being happy,' 'being' is a gerund?"  ANSWER:  Yes!  By Jove, I think you've got it!!!

Comment: @drPangloss : You asked: "Would you agree that not only is 'John's being absent' a thing but also that 'being absent' is a thing itself and belongs to John, in the same sense as 'John's disposition'?"  ANSWER:  Yes, I most certainly would agree with that.

Answer (score 6):

In traditional grammar the verb *being* would be considered a gerund in the Original Poster's example. The reason for this is that the clause it heads (*John being absent*) is the complement of a preposition.

The distinction between a participle and a gerund is troublesome. It looks as if the difference is to do with parts of speech or something similar. In fact, the real distinction has to do with the grammatical relations (syntactic functions).

In traditional grammar, a gerund is an *-ing* form of a verb that heads a clause functioning as:

- Subject of a clause
- Object of a verb
- Complement of a preposition

In all other situations, an *-ing* form of the verb is considered a participle. Clauses headed by participles are often modifiers in clause or phrase structure.

Some modern grammars such as the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (2002) regard the distinction between gerunds and participles as unhelpful, because it blurs the line between what type of word the *-ing* form is and what job it is doing in the sentence. They use the term *gerund-participle* to refer to the type of word regardless of what job the clause is doing in the larger sentence.

Comment: I would say that _John / John's being absent_ is a non-finite participial clause (not a phrase). To be clear, are you saying that too? I wondered because you use the word 'phrase' later in your answer.

Comment: This is right, and see also Benjamin Harmon's answer above.

Comment: @Greg Lee What is right?

Comment: @BillJ, I think  Araucaria and Harman are both right.  Araucaria has a more general view.

Comment: @Greg Lee Yes, but we are talking about the finer points of grammar here. Unlike a phrase, a clause has a subject-predicate relationship, and can be negated etc. The OP’s example has a subject “John” and a predicate “being absent”, so it's clearly a clause. I think it’s really important to make that distinction, otherwise you get people thinking that _John being absent_ is a noun phrase when it's actually a clause.

Comment: @BillJ, It's both a clause and a noun phrase.  It's really the same issue that Araucaria discussed.  Sentences have structures that look different seen from downstairs than when seen from upstairs.  "being" is a downstairs verb but an upstairs noun -- hence a gerund.  "John being absent" is a downstairs clause (which is why it can have a downstairs verb) but an upstairs noun phrase (which is why it can have an upstairs noun, the gerund).

Comment: @Greg Lee Araucaria That's fine if you take a clause to be sub-type of phrase. But if no distinction is made, learners will never be able to tell a subject-predicate structure (clause) from a simple head/dependent one phrase). Btw, I've no idea what you mean by 'upstairs/downstairs' here?

Comment: @Greg Lee What you've just said about _being_ being a gerund proves what I've been saying. It's not a gerund in the OP's example but a verb - simple as that.

Comment: @Araucaria I don't follow you. Where's the subject-predicate structure in, say, the NP "My lovely new car"? And how can you negate an NP? And clauses, not NPs can contain auxiliary verbs. There's a big distinction to be made

Comment: @BillJ, When a phrase with several parts is made a part of a larger phrase, the larger phrase is the upstairs and the phrase contained within it is the downstairs.  In the example, "John being absent" is object of the preposition "at", which makes it a noun phrase, with (presumably) a noun head "being".  That's the upstairs view. But this phrase, in regard to the relationship of its parts to one another, looking around downstairs, is a sentence, with aux verb "be" and subject "John".

Comment: @ Greg Lee If you scroll down a bit, you'll see the messages I exchanged with the OP in which I highlighted the distinction between gerundial nouns and verbs.

Comment: @Greg Lee. Ah, I see. What you call the 'upstairs' phrase', I call the 'matrix phrase'. The expression "at John being present" is a prep phrase, whose complement is the embedded non-finite clause "John being present". I thought we'd covered that point, but maybe not.

Comment: No one makes more sense on this subject of how nominalization works than McCawley in **TSPE**.  I learned a lot from his discussion (some of which I have forgotten).

Comment: @Greg Lee. I follow Huddleston & Pullum's award-winning Cambridge Grammar. I've corresponded with both authors on most points of grammar over the years, so I'd like to think I know just a little bit about what I'm talking about.