# A question about “fluctuating” vs "fluctuated"

Tags: word-usage

The following sentence is a sentence in my composition, and I think it is reasonable to write a sentence in this way. However, a grammar checker has said that I should use "fluctuating" rather than "fluctuated". Is it a false negative check result?

> Except for the amount of goods transported by railway fluctuated over 28 years, a significant increase can be seen in the number of goods transported by other methods.

[image: error]

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you think this is a false negative. As well as why you'd use a grammar checker that delivers false results. (In the mean time, your original sentence is ungrammatical, so your checker is for once correct at least in pointing it out, though not necessarily in how it should be fixed.)

Comment: I think "fluctuated" is a correct usage because the thing occurs in the past 28 years.

Comment: _For_ requires a noun or gerund. You could say 'Except _that_ the amount fluctuated'.

Comment: @zhen what you say is certainly true if your sentence is one word long. However, that is not the case here, we have the rest of the sentence to account for. So, for example, if you want to use the past tense, it can be "except for the amount of goods transported by railway *that* fluctuated over 28 years...". And even that is questionable, because while grammatical, it's very clumsily worded. So really what you need to do is re-write the sentence. But at any rate, what you have now is not correct. Also, note that "fluctuating" is not present tense. It indicates no tense at all, only an aspect.

Comment: I think this is actually a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4554/191178